# Orchard CMS VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, orchardcms

Just wondering, does Orchard CMS supports VB.Net (without obviously converting from C#)?

I looked at the source code at CodePlex and they are all in C#.

Comment: Define what you mean by supports

Comment: Sorry I mean, does the Orchard team or other known reliable sources distribute (and maintain with releases/updates) the source code in VB.Net? Or, is there anyone out there who does Orchard in VB.Net without converting the C# source code themselves. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you want the code in vb.net? There's probably other ways to do whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: I am a C# developer myself - but I am happened to be assigned on a project with a team of all VB.Net developers - and do the prototype for them in Orchard. If there's no VB.Net support out there for Orchard - I need to inform them of this, and either they will happily accept Orchard in C# or look at other CMS.

Comment: Fair enough, though with .net you can write any additional assemblies you need in VB. This isn't going to help you modify any existing code, though. Have your team embrace C# - you're going to be hard pressed finding quality .net applications written in VB.

Comment: So I guess what you're saying VB.Net developers out there when developing Orchards still see the source codes in C# but only writes the Modules (since it's on different project) in VB.Net?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this cms but yes, so long as what you're doing is built independently from orchards code you should be able to add to it with VB modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, VB is not and will very probably never be supported.